# Need some explanation on answers about solving an ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an ODE $\frac{dy}{dx} + y = \sin 2x$. Now I solved the ode where

$$y=Ae^{-x} + \frac{1}{5} \sin 2x - \frac{2}{5} \cos 2x.$$

The question wants me to use the solution to find u(x) for this ODE:

$$\frac{d^2u}{dx^2} + \frac{du}{dx} = \sin 2x.$$ 
Apparently if I substitute $du/dx$ as $y$ then I integrate both sides I get $u(x)$ .But why is $du/dx=y$ in this second ODE? Clearly the first ODE is a first order differentiation and the second is a second order? Any  help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are making use of what you learned from the first equation to solve the second.  You can simply define $\frac {du}{dx}=y$ and then integrate the solution to the first equation to get an equation for $u$.

Comment: But how can I just randomly substitute any value as du/dx?I might as well say du/dx=x then I just integrate and get u.There must be some similarity between the first ODE and second ODE that I'm not getting?

Comment: You can do that if you are interested in that $u$, which is different from the $u$ in the problem.  The approach in the problem would be useful if you started with the second equation but didn't know how to solve it.  You might then create the first equation, solve it, and use the result to solve the second.

Comment: That's right, reduction of order. Say you started with the second and make the substitution $v=u'$ so then $v'+v=\sin(2t)$ which is the first equation. Solve for $v$, then go back through the substitution to solve for $u$

Comment: It is similar to $u$ substitution in integration.  You just define $u$ to be something that is useful it getting to the solution.  Since we didn't have $u$ in the problem before, you can define it however you want as long as the definition is self-consistent.  It can be an art to come up with the right definition.

Comment: Okay so if the second ODE is 2* du/dx do I just multiply 2 by y then integrate?And does this method hold if the second ODE is 2d^u/dx^2 and instead?

Comment: You can multiply the equation through by $2$ or anything else.  For that to help all the terms in the second equation need to be twice the value in the first equation.